# How to make actionButton runs code.R to an uploaded dataset?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Am doing R Shiny web App that allows user to upload particular dataset from several sources.
The app allows user to upload data first then preprocess it using existing code.R
for example if df1 uploaded must clean it using code1.R and so on for df2 and df3.

***The code as follows***

```
    server = function(input, output,session){

      vals <- reactiveValues()
      observeEvent(input$run, {
        vals$korek_out <- korek()
        showModal(modalDialog("calculation finished!"))
      })
      
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi Adam, in order to help you we need reproducible example (all code and data to reproduce the question). Also please only one question.

Comment: Hi, how to make actionButton run .R code to an uploaded dataset ?

Comment: This question is good. Please update the post with it and simplify the code to the minimal part that demonstrates the actionButton click does not run the R code on an uploaded dataset.

Comment: Code is now shorter but it would be better to provide a full working example that allows to select and upload the file, and click the button. Also include a minimal code that would be in the code1.R file

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem above and be able to upload and preprocess data based function I wrote using this method

```
observeEvent(input$cleank, {
      output$contents <-  renderTable({inFile <- korek(kork = kdat)})
```

where korek(kork) is a user defined function runs from code.R